# right place for "these days"

Tags: grammaticality

Option 1- I am presently in Singapore on a Business Visa and will be returning to India on 9th May.

Option 2 - I am in Singapore on a Business Visa these days and will be returning to India on 9th May

My original sentence was option 2 but one of the answers to similar questions suggested the usage of "presently" which looked more logical.

What will the right place for these days in option 2?

Comment: It's a matter of _register_. _These days_ can be perceived as slightly informal, but the sentence implies a rather formal setting. However, many speakers of English would find _presently_ a bit overly formal or possibly even dated - I would use _currently_.

Comment: @WS2 The contrastive requirement is a good spot. Certainly worthy of an answer if you can find [a supporting reference, perhaps at CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/nowadays-these-days-or-today); probably the lack of a dictionary counterexample would suffice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED has obliged perfectly.

Comment: With more acceptable examples: ' I don’t watch TV / drink beer / get out /  ... very much these days. ' **or** 'These days, I don't get out very much,'

Comment: 'At this time' would work instead of 'these days' in your second variant; it has the same distribution as 'these days': ' I am in Singapore on a Business Visa at this time and will be ...' /  ' At this time, I am in Singapore on a Business Visa, and will be ...'. Even ' I am, at this time, in Singapore on a Business Visa, and will be ...'. But it's as formal as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

"These days" is normally idiomatic only as an alternative to something that happened in the middle to distant past. e.g. "In Britain they do not send children down mines and up chimneys these days, (as they did in the early 19th century).

Or "With the advent of social media, not as many people are reading newspapers these days".

The way it is used in your option 2 is NOT IDIOMATIC. I would have used "at the moment".

The following is the OED entry for the adverbial phrase *these days*. The examples are all contrasting the present with some past time.

> f. these days advb. phr., nowadays, at present.
>
> 1936   R. Lehmann Weather in Streets i. v. 97   An estate like this
>   must be a terrible problem these days.
>
> 1948   M. Dickens Joy & Josephine i. iv. 132   ‘Play golf?’ Mr. Gray
>   asked George, who answered: ‘Not these days,’ as if he ever had.
>
> 1960   S. Barstow Kind of Loving ii. iii. 181   He looks as though
>   he's walked out of an American picture. It's all Yankeeland these
>   days.
>
> 1981   Woman 5 Dec. 5/1   These days women are educated to expect some
>   choice in how they spend their lives.

Comment: Call me disloyal, but I prefer the [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/nowadays-these-days-or-today) article: << We can use _nowadays, these days_ or _today_ as adverbs meaning ‘at the present time, in comparison with the past’:

I don’t watch TV very much nowadays. There’s so much rubbish on. It’s not like it used to be. //

Young people nowadays don’t respect their teachers any more. >> But certainly +1 for the spot and research.